# How to see custom logged events in Crashlytics?

Tags: android, logging, crashlytics

I have included the following code in one of my app's Activities,

```
        Crashlytics.setInt("Total minutes used", (int) (long) (prefs.getLong("totalMinutesUsed", 0)));
        Crashlytics.setInt("Distinct Days Launched", (int) (long) (prefs.getLong("distinctDaysLaunchCount", 1)));
        Crashlytics.setInt("Share count", (int) (long) (prefs.getLong("shareCount", 0)));
        Crashlytics.setInt("Launch count", (int) (long) (prefs.getLong("launchCount", 0)));
```

I would like to know, how can I see this tracked data in Crashlytics web portal?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. You will see this logged in individual sessions at logs and keys. Go to a crash and click 'View all sessions' to navigate through your sessions data.